# Add a class to a navigation item once it is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sinatra

I have navigation set up like so:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li><a href="/questions/all">All</a></li>
  <li><a href="/questions/popular">Popular</a></li>
  <li><a href="/questions/fun">Fun</a></li>
</ul>
```

When one of these is clicked, it maps to my Sinatra route (i.e. `get '/questions/:filter' do...`). Clicking on any of them updates the page, but they all still use the same `.erb` view.

I'm trying to figure out how I can apply the class "`active`" to the `<li>` navigation item that is currently being viewed. This way, the nav item will be highlighted so users will know what view they are on (without having to look at the actual URL).

Any help would be much appreciated. I have access jQuery if needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `window.location.pathname` variable to select the anchor tag.

```
$('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active')
```

Comment: ah, cool. i need to add the class to the <li> and not the <a> though. not sure how to do that exactly. essentially, i need to find the li that corresponds to that pathname to add the class.

Comment: `$('a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active')`

Comment: this is brilliant! I've never thought of doing it on the client, let alone so elegantly!

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can add a class to indicate that it's active:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Replace (this) with whichever div element you wish to add the class.  This will allow you to then style based on the div class id.

Comment: i found this function, but i'm not sure _when_ to actually make this call. i only want to add the class to the nav item that matches the current page in view.

Comment: thanks. i actually ended up adding a unique id to each <li> item and then used jquery to target the appropriate one to add class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.nav a[href="' + window.location.pathname + '"]').addClass('active')
 });
```

Comment: ah this adds the active class to the <a> instead of the corresponding <li>, so it does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reloading the page, you could use ruby through the in the erb template to the add the class to the li tag if the current route matches the li tag's associated anchor href.

In the controller:

```
...
@body_class = "page2"
@nav_links = ['page1', 'page2', 'page3']
...
```

In the view template:

```
<body class="<%= @body_class %>">
...
<ul class="nav">
    <% @nav_links.each do |link| %>
        <li <% if link.eql?(@body_class) %>class="selected"<% end %>><a href="<%= link %>"><%= link %></a></li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
...
</body>
```

If you only want to use the current URL and skip the controller:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="<% if request.fullpath.eql?('/this/items/endpoint') %>selected<% end %>"><a href="/this/items/endpoint">Page 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i am using ruby, but not actually sure how to do this – sounds like a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that your view is served everytime by your sinatra webapp, i'd suggest you to add logic into it with a variable and a simple if statement. A kind of (in php) :

```
<ul>
<?php
  $filters = array("all", "popular", "fun");
  foreach($filters as $filter):
?>

<li>
<a href="/questions/<?php echo $filter; ?>"
  <?php if ($filter == $currentfilter) { ?>class="active"<?php }; ?>>
  <?php echo $filter; ?>
</a>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

It's important that your view is served like that directly. It's not the business of javascript to add a class to active page, unless you're using a javascript based navigation (full of ajax, etc).